# Getting the Principal inside an ErrorWebExceptionHandler in Webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I wrote a working error handler for my webflux application.
The problem arose when I tried to add the username of the logged Principal to exceptions... I see using the debugger that no context is found inside the ReactiveSecurityContextHolder, so "N/A" is always used as username value...

Note that:

1. If you remove the call to restPrincipalService.getPrincipalUsername() the handler works as expected
2. The method restPrincipalUsername.getPrincipalUsername() when called in a Controller or Service works just well, and authentication is working

Here the code:

```
@Component
@Order(-2)
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Slf4j
public class GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    private RestPrincipalService principalService;

    public GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes, ApplicationContext applicationContext, ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer) {
        super(errorAttributes, new WebProperties.Resources(), applicationContext);
        super.setMessageWriters(serverCodecConfigurer.getWriters());
        super.setMessageReaders(serverCodecConfigurer.getReaders());
    }

    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(
      ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {

        return RouterFunctions.route(
          RequestPredicates.all(), this::renderErrorResponse);
    }

    private Mono<ServerResponse> renderErrorResponse(ServerRequest request) {

        Map<String, Object> errorPropertiesMap = getErrorAttributes(request,
           ErrorAttributeOptions.of(ErrorAttributeOptions.Include.EXCEPTION, ErrorAttributeOptions.Include.MESSAGE));

        return principalService.getPrincipalUsername().flatMap(username -> {
            errorPropertiesMap.put("username", username);
            String exception= errorPropertiesMap.get("exception").toString();
            //...business logic on exception and properties, using username
            return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.valueOf((Integer) errorPropertiesMap.get("status")))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(errorPropertiesMap));
        });

    }
}
```

The getPrincipalUsername() implementation:

```
public Mono<String> getPrincipalUsername() {
    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(ctx->
                    ctx.getAuthentication())
            .filter(authentication ->
                    authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated())
            .map(authentication ->
                    ((Principal)authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just("N/A")); //No user authenticated
}
```

So the question is: why is the getPrincipalUsername working only in services and controllers, and not there? And how can I achieve the expected result?

Edit: I know, the request has a method getPrincipal, but it doesn't work either... I see using the debugger that the default implementation is:

(org/springframework/web/server/adapter/DefaultServerWebExchange.java)

```
@Override
public <T extends Principal> Mono<T> getPrincipal() {
    return Mono.empty();
}
```